# class template deduction from pointer to member

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

As one of the class template parameters I need to use a pointer to member:

```
template <class Base, typename Member, Member Base::*m>
class MemPtrTestUgly
{
...
};
```

This needs to be used as

```
struct S
{
    int t;
}

MembPtrTestUgly <S, int, &S::t> m;
```

But I want to use it as this:

```
MemPtrTestNice<S, &S::t> m;
```

The member type is deduced from the member pointer. I cannot use function template, as the `MemPtrTest` class is not supposed to be instantiated (there are just some static functions that will be used). Is there a way how to do it in pure C++03 (no Boost or TR1)?

Comment: I doubt, if it's possible with C++03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use partial specialization and get a pretty nice-looking implementation:

```
template <typename TMember, TMember MemberPtr>
class MemPtrTest;

template <typename TBase, typename TType, TType TBase::*MemberPtr>
class MemPtrTest<TType TBase::*, MemberPtr>
{
    // ...
};
```

This would be used as:

```
MemPtrTest<decltype(&S::t), &S::t> m;
```

Of course, this requires `decltype` or an equivalent, if you don't want to implicitly specify the member type.

Comment: `decltype` is in C++11. Another option, `typeof`, is for gcc only. Are there any other options?

Comment: In order to have a value as a template parameter, you need to be able to construct the type of that value in the template parameter list. The most likely workaround is a context in which C++ can infer a type from a regular value, which basically comes down to implementing `decltype` yourself.

Comment: You could produce an instance of this class inside a helper function, using template argument deduction, but that doesn't help you if you want to name the class itself.